# Does removing a user from a group revoke their ownership privileges?

Tags: windows, ntfs, file-permissions, active-directory

This may be a naïve question, but I'm concerned about file ownership and group access under NTFS file systems and in a Windows AD environment.

Let's say that Jim-Bob created a folder, `\stuff`, and put a text document, `\stuff\words.txt`, in that folder under the share `\\totally-hipaa-compliant-server\ultrasecure`. He had the appropriate permission to do so because he's a part of the `Super Trusted Users` group, which is required for access to the `ultrasecure` share.

Jim-Bob then causes an incident and gets himself removed from the `Super Trusted Users` group.
Does removing him from the group remove his ownership of the folder and file? If he has ownership of the file and folder, can he still access that file and folder despite having no permission to the `ultrasecure` share?

I realize this sounds a little academic, but I'm listing file permissions on a share and seeing old users as owners, and the users seem to have ownership permissions. I'm not sure if this is cause for concern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Removing him from the group does not remove him as the owner of the file.  However, it does remove his ability to get to the file.

NTFS file/folder ownership grants the owner to add/change/remove permissions of a file or folder.  However, if the user can not access that file, it is a moot point.

It would probably be a good idea to change the owner of the file to someone else in that group though.  You never know where you might have made a share/permissions error and that person still has access to the file.

Comment: Looks like ownership isn't a problem, thanks. Turns out explicitly adding a single user permission to a subfolder can be... Guess I get to scan all the subfolders anyway.